# How relations I should use? How draw diagram?

Tags: database, relational-database, diagram

I have problem because I am not sure it is possible and if it is which kind of relations I should use, my issue looks like:

Table `Users`

```
Id
```

Table `Transaction`

```
Id
IdProducentUser
IdConsumerUser
```

each columns are required.

And in this case both `IdProducentUser` and `IdConsumerUser` should be `foreign key` so each User can have a lot of Transactions but I don't know which kind of relation I shoud use and how I should draw it on diagram.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does an item always have exactly two users? Could there be more/fewer sometimes? When I see column names like User1 and User2 I get worried.

Comment: Could you please describe your model in plain English?

Comment: @BrianWillis It have always exactly two users. I'll edit my post in a moment

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly two users in Transaction then you can create two relations one-to-many:

[image]

But if your user can take part in multiple Transactions and your Transaction can have multiple Users then it will be a many-to-many relation which in second phase of modeling should be drawn by additional extra entity, which breaks many-to-many relation.